# What is the function of forkN?

Tags: c, operating-system, fork, semaphore, multitasking

First time working with C code and was hit with this.  Is anyone familiar with "**forkN**"? I've read about fork but I can't find any reference to the "**N**"... To put it into context, I have to identify how many processes are running in the code below.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  forkN(6);
}

void forkN(int count) {
  if(count > 0) {
    fork();
    forkN(count-1);
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's a function that they defined right here.   What don't you understand?

Comment: That's indeed a bad example to start with. Forget it and take the next one. Come back to this in three month.  Out of curiosity: Your C class really started with this one?

Comment: Btw: `int main()` ought to return an `int`!

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I'm actually in an operating systems class which should have had a pre-req for some knowledge in C.

Answer (score 3):

The thing you have to remember about fork is it returns twice, so using `3` I will show you the analysis.

```
 int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    forkN(6)
 }

 void forkN ( int count ) {
    if(count > 0) {
            fork();
            //returns twice, once for the parent process, once for the child. 
            forkN(count-1);
            //Both processes call forkN
    } 
 }

--main process -- forkN(3) -- if(3 > 0)-- fork() --- forkN(2) -- if(2>0) -- fork().. forkN(1)... 
                                            |Child                            |
                                            -------- forkN(2) -- if(2>0) -----|-fork()..
                                                                              |   |
                                                                              |   -------forkN(1)..
                                                                              |----- forkN(1)..
enter code here
```

As you can see it gets complicated. The thing to know is every time `fork()` is called, 2 processes call into `forkN()`, and each of those 2 processes create a child process of their own.

Comment: Thank you for breaking this down for me.  Makes much more sense now!

Answer (score 0):

The `forkN()` function is defined right in your sample source and is terribly obvious, is it possible that the "N" is confusing you? The answer is that "forkN" is simply a name of a locally-defined function, and could just as easily have been named "repeatedly_do()" or "countdown_lots_of_times()". As for identifying how many processes are running, the function named "forkN()" (or "repeatedly_do()" or "countdown_lots_of_times()") is, as you can see, calling `fork()` recursively. It should be fairly simply to plot the process creations and count them (or you could just exponentiate.)